# Chart JS. Attempting to bind to Model. Razor code not working

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, chart.js

I am attempting to bind properties from my Razor Model to a ChartJS dataset. However, it appears my javascript is not compiling at runtime and never ran at all. Here is my javascript.

```
alert(@Model.reject_count.FirstOrDefault());
var data = @Model.reject_count.ToList();
var labels = @Model.messages.ToList();
var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Blue",
            "Yellow"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [300, 50, 100],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ]
            }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you put the code inside a `window.onload = function(){ } `?

Comment: The way that you are attempting to bind the data is the problem. Unles I am mistaken, the result of `var data = @Model.reject_count.ToList();` wil not be a list of data, but rather the name of the generic list type. You will need to serialize the data in your model before assigning it to JS elements.

Comment: I'll attempt to serialize the data. Thank you for the tip!